# Unable to create a list from a custom list template in gallery - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, list-template

I have saved a list as a template including the content and now ) can see the template in the list templates as well.

When I go to a sub site underneath that web and try to create an app using the template, I'm not able find the template to choose from.

I have tried many trouble shooting steps like recreatinging the templates, ensuring the server and publishing features are active and so on, but still I can not see the template in template gallery while creating the new app/list.

Any thoughts on what is different in SharePoint Online/2013?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the language of the site collection where you exported and where you are trying to import are the same.

If not, rename the stp file as cab file and extract the manifest.xml

Change the value inside the language tag

```
<Language>1036</Language>
```

[image]

Once this is done, in the command prompt, navigate to the location of the manifest.xml file and use the below command to create cab file

```
makecab manifest.xml [Name of the list template].stp
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps as a workaround for this problem:

1. Click on site action - site contents - add an app    Create a
   custom list Now click on the list - go to list settings and save this
   list as a template
2. Now click on add an app - select the "OOB
   list template" and when you get the pop up to name the list - click
   on advanced options

   Now copy the URL - navigate to the URL
   decoder and decode the URL in my case it was
   https://sharepointadmin.sharepoint.com/sites/Team/_layouts/15/new.aspx?CustomTemplate=OOB
   list
   temp.stp&FeatureId={00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100}&ListTemplate=100&

   3. Now navigate to the original list template gallery and copy the feature ID
      for the original template for list which has issues
   4. Now replace the template name with the original template of the list
      in the above decoded URL  in my case its
      Mstesttemplate.stp    And the feature ID
      {00BFEA71-5xgdD-4CA0-96C2-6A47775C01wee}    And at the end of the URL
      ListTemplate=100 which is the old template not supported replace
      that by 150   So the final URL should look like this -
      https://sharepointadmin.sharepoint.com/sites/Team/_layouts/15/new.aspx?CustomTemplate=MSTestTemplate.stp&FeatureId={00xzBxccvxcvEA71-513D-4CA0-96C2-6A47775C0119}&ListTemplate=150&
        Now browse this URL and give a name to the list and your list
      will be created using the original template